Countifs with year and other reference cells with text
Looking for a formula for 3 criteria in google sheets to count if all are TRUE:
Number of entries that equal a specific region
Number of entries that say "Yes"
Number of entries that have a date submitted in 2024
Column A is the Regions: Eastern, Western, Southern
Column B is Accepted, with Yes or No in the cells
Column C is Date Submitted (date format is MM/DD/YY)
I would like to know how many Accepted entries there were for the Western Region in 2024.
I tried combinations of Countifs() formulas, but I am not sure how to get the date equals the year 2024.
Google Sheets Image:


The beginning of the [tag:google-sheets] tag wiki reads Do NOT share spreadsheets/images as the only source of data. Use markdown TEXT tables instead.. Also, Please do not upload images of code/data/errors..

Also, you'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

In relation to the previous comment, you may use Tables as a reference so that other community members can easily copy and paste the data on their own spreadsheets. You can also Make an anonymous sample document if you're having trouble creating them in the question.

Try this:
=COUNTIFS(A2:A, "Western", B2:B, "Yes", ARRAYFORMULA(YEAR(C2:C)), 2024)

OUTPUT

You may also try this:
=COUNTIFS(A2:A, "Western", B2:B, "Yes", C2:C, ">=" & DATE(2024,1,1), C2:C, "<=" & DATE(2024,12,31))

OUTPUT


In the example, I did not see any Yes on Western, so I changed for testing purposes.

REFERENCE

COUNTIFS


Here are few other approaches.
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A="Southern")*(B2:B="Yes")*(C2:C>=DATE(2024,1,1))*(C2:C<=DATE(2024,12,31)))
=SUMPRODUCT(--(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A="Southern",B2:B="Yes",C2:C>=DATE(2024,1,1),C2:C<=DATE(2024,12,31))<>""))
=QUERY(A2:C,"select count(A) where A='Southern' and B='Yes' and C>= date '2024-01-01' and C<= date '2024-12-31' label count(A) ''")


